# How to add a column to a Power Query table loaded onto Excel?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a Power Query with an SQL source that is Loaded into a table in Excel. I have tried to add a column to that table, so that a user can add comments to a specific record of that table, but when the data gets refreshed and new records are added, the comment stays in the same cell, but the corresponding data is moved around.

Is there a way around that?

Comment: See this article: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately in the article, the source an Excel table (with user input). In my situation the source of my Excel table is a Power Query with an SQL query as a source. I get the error message HRESULT : 0x800A03EC on loading to Excel.

Comment: OK, found out the problem was that I had left VLOOKUPs in the added columns. Works just fine now that I pasted as values.